# .htaccess help - not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite all .php into .html,,, so i created a `.htaccess` file and added

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
```

but when it seems not working...

here i uploaded all files - http://www.fellowindian.com/ca/index.php  & http://www.fellowindian.com/ca/page1.php

Comment: You know...you kinda need to approve some answers...sometimes... You don't seem to do that.

Comment: Is Apache definitely picking up the .htaccess file? (Put some junk in and see if it spits tacks.) Is there anything in the httpd error logs? Have you tried restarting httpd? You really need to put a bit more effort into problem solving before you post.

Comment: i can only do that after it worked for me...

Comment: Apache is picking my .htaccess file ( i tried putting is random text )... i am not a great programmer and don't know much about httpd... can uplease say me where is it ?

Comment: @ajreal - Vlad.P is talking about another question...  don't forget that this is programming q&a site...

Comment: @Vlad.P:  Give the guy a break - including this question, he's asked a total of three, two within the past half hour or so.

Comment: @Ashok - Any changes on apache configuration, you need to restart the server (Did you?) Please follow the things to check mentioned by @middaparka

Comment: @GreenMatt - you are very week in maths,,, i only asked 2 question...

Comment: @Ashok:  I don't think I'm weak in math - I minored in it in college and later got a Masters in Physics.  Your SO profile shows 3 questions asked, 2 within about 30 minutes of the time I made my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Do you have mod_mime installed on Apache.
2: Are you sure that .htaccess is executing.

Simple test would be to see if it can rewrite your urls to add / remove www from it.
Example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine
On RewriteBase / RewriteCond
%{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mycee\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$
http://www.mycee.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

3: Which user is the owner of the .htaccess file and what is its attributes?

4: Check that the AllowOverride directive is set in your apache config and not set to None.
   Test by putting invalid directives in the .htaccess file and reloading the page. 
   If the apache error log doesn't show any errors, it's not executing.

5: If you're on shared hosting, check with your host if they have AllowOverride enabled or not.

Personally, I think the best place to put the AddType directive would be in apache's httpd.conf as .htaccess puts a performance hit on your server, but in the case of shared hosting, .htaccess is usually the only option available.

Comment: my .htaccess file is working ( i check by putting some junk datas and it got loged ),,, AllowOverride directive is enabled...

Comment: Try using AddType instead of AddHandler, I think AddHandler is for running PHP as CGI.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to redirect something.php to something.html, you could do

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .php$
RewriteRule (.*?).php $1.html
```

Comment: It is very likely that he wants it the other way around.

Comment: Check your error log, see what's going on in there... I tested this before I posted it, and it forwarded over properly.

Comment: i got this error [Tue Dec 07 23:22:16 2010] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/ca/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration